# What's a good way to debug issues with X forwarding over ssh where just some applications won't run?

Tags: ssh, debugging, xforwarding

As far as I understand it, X forwarding is usually pretty simple. Once I can run some things like `xeyes` or `gimp` over ssh, complex applications like `firefox`/`iceweasel` should also be able to run. However, I have one notebook from where I can't get a forwarded iceweasel (or icedove) session via ssh and X forwarding.

Background info in this question: [Newer versions of Mozilla (Iceweasel / Icedove) not working when X forwarding is used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64335/newer-versions-of-mozilla-iceweasel-icedove-not-working-when-x-forwarding-is)

Since this may either be a bug in mozialla iceweasel and icedove for new-ish versions, or an issue with X (forwarding) on the one particular notebook, or a feature of X forwarding that's required by just some applications, I feel I need to debug the issue thoroughly.

I need advice on how to debug. Things like calling ssh using the verbose option. Log files to look at while calling the nonfunctional X-forwarded applications. There has to be some clue, somewhere.

Comment: you haven't given very much information for any of us to effectively provide advise.  What have you done to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

X11 forwarding only works for the core protocol and some extensions. It obviously doesn't work for extensions like the MIT-SHM extension.

My guess is that one of the graphics-related extensions, since browsers are now assuming that using OpenGL-accelerated rendering is both available and faster.

I haven't used any of them myself, but Google tells me you can get a dump of the protocol with these tools: xtruss, scope, xmsgtrace. Then, look for an error that looks related to extensions.

Comment: Has anyone tried these methods `xtruss`, `scope`, and/or `xmsgtrace`?